# Paramiko run command fails with Kerberos authentication issue

Tags: ssh, hdfs, kerberos, paramiko

I have to fetch the files from hdfs using python code and Im using paramiko client connection to run the command on hadoop file system.

A code snippet as follows

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(server,
                username=username,
                password=password)
    ssh.exec_command('hdfs dfs -cat '+ file_path)
```

This works fine and i can get the file content from hdfs as required. However, if i run this for multiple files in sequence or run other commands to find or list files, after a few commands it starts failing with error message

> Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException:
> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]

Even if I try to do kinitad before running each command, still i get this error randomly.

How can i get rid of this error?

Comment: Not specific enough. There should be a list of `caused by:` entries in the stack trace. Without these, it's a bit like answering to _"how can I get rid of networking issues"_ (duh, what kind?)

Comment: And even after analysing the stack trace, you may need some deep / unpleasant / time-consuming / highly technical debugging sessions for this kind of Kerberos troubleshooting. Good luck. Recommended reading: _Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"_ (a GitBook by Steve Loughran)